# Trying to pass the content of an editText from one class to another in android but m unable to do so....m getting a null pointer exception?

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if (hasValidInput()) {
        //showActivityIndicators();
        Intent result = new Intent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("username", "abcd");
        b.putString("apiKey", "hello");
        b.putString("server", getAuthServer());
        result.putExtra("accountInfo", b);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        //Account acc = new Account();
        //Bundle c = new Bundle();
        //acc.setPassword(c.getString("apiKey"));
        //acc.setUsername(c.getString("username"));
        //acc.setAuthServerV2(c.getString("server"));
        //Log.d("info", "the set server was " + c.getString("server"));
        //Log.d("info", "the server is " + acc.getAuthServerV2());
        //accounts.add(acc);
        //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 
        EditText mSaved = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.containername);
         //editor.putString("text", mSaved.getText().toString()); 
         SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE );
         Editor editor1 = prefs.edit();
         editor1.putString("name",mSaved.getText().toString());
         editor1.commit();


        //login();

        finish();
    } else {
        showAlert("Required Fields Missing", "Username and API Key are required.");
    }

}
```

I'm calling it in a different class in the following function as...

```
 public class CreateContainerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HttpBundle> {
    private CloudServersException exception;

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        showDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpBundle doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpBundle bundle = null;
        //EditText containerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.containername);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);  
        String containerName = prefs.getString("name", null);
        Log.d("info", containerName);
        try {

            bundle = (new ContainerManager(getContext())).create(containerName);
        } catch (CloudServersException e) {
            exception = e;
        }
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HttpBundle bundle) {
        hideDialog();
        /*HttpResponse response = bundle.getResponse();
        if (response != null) {
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 201) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            } else {
                CloudServersException cse = parseCloudServersException(response);
                if ("".equals(cse.getMessage())) {
                    showError("There was a problem creating your container.", bundle);
                } else {
                    showError("There was a problem creating your container: " + cse.getMessage() + " See details for more information.", bundle);
                }
            }
        } else if (exception != null) {
            showError("There was a problem creating your container: " + exception.getMessage()+" See details for more information.", bundle);               
        }*/
        finish();
    }
}
```

in the above code I'm trying to make a container in the cloud using the username
but it gives a null pointer and the app stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you get `SharedPreferences` use this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

and whenever you get the `Editor` use this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

Also, where are you getting the `NullPointerException`? Is it on the line

```
String containerName = prefs.getString("name", null);
```

where you are trying to get the stored name preference? If it is on this line, then your are indeed storing the preference incorrectly. If not, then it is another problem. Please provide a logcat or specify exactly where the exception is happening. Without this information, my best guess is what I provided above.